# Sort mysql data by count and timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to have a 'trending' search terms spot on my site that returns both the searches with most counts, but only from the last 24 hours.

The query I'm using to return the searches with most counts is:

```
  SELECT searchstring 
    FROM trending 
ORDER BY count DESC 
   LIMIT 5
```

My table columns are:

- id
- searchstring
- count
- timestamp

Comment: What type the `timestamp` field is?

Comment: timestamp is actually timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT searchstring 
FROM trending 
WHERE 
  timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
```